Gradient Texture not working properly
I want to have a spherical gradient texture applied to my Circle Object. However, when I do this the circle of the gradient is very small. I applied all transforms and made sure the Origin is at the centre of the Object.
When I decrease the Scale on the Mapping node to 0.15 it does make the white circle larger, but the video that I am watching does not change anything within the Mapping node, so I am curious if there is something else that I am missing.


Typically, you need to hook up your gradient texture node to a color ramp node, like this:


The circle in the question seems to be larger than a default circle with a radius of 1. Using a Color Ramp like in your answer will only make the transition from white to black sharper but not change the absolute size of the spherical gradient in any way.

You are using Object coordinates from the Texture Coordinate node. This means, the center of the coordinate system is at the origin of the object and the X/Y/Z values are (if the scale of the object is applied) simply the dimensions in X/Y/Z direction.
The Spherical gradient goes from (0, 0, 0) goes from white (1) to black (0) to a distance of 1 from the center in each direction. With the texture coordinates based on the object origin this means it goes black towards X = -1 m and X = +1 m, Y = -1 m and Y = + 1 m and Z = - 1 m and Z = +1 m. It is white where X = Y = Z = 0 m.
The circle is flat, so we can ignore the Z direction. This is what it looks like on a default circle with a radius of 1 m, the gradient fades from white in the center to black at -1 m and +1 m in X and Y direction:

But your circle looks a lot larger in the screenshot. The thing is, when you scaled it in Object Mode and applied the scale or you scaled it in Edit Mode, the dimensions it has are its "real" dimensions (I'm not going to write a tutorial on scaling and applying transformations now). So if the circle has a radius of 5 m, then the gradient still just goes from -1 m to +1 m although the border of the circle is now at -5 m and +5 m:

And this is why you have to adjust the scale of the coordinates. To get the same result on a circle with a radius of 5 m like a circle with a radius of 1 m, you have to set the scale to 1/5 = 0.2 because the circle border goes from -5 m to +5 m, so scaling with 0.2 translates it to -5 m · 0.2 = -1 m and +5 m · 0.2 = +1 m.

Another way would be using a Map Range node. When you know the values range from -5 to +5 and you want them to be in the -1 to +1 range, simply use the values as From Min/Max and To Min/Max:

This is when you are using the Texture Coordinate > Object output. Since you did not say which video you are watching I would assume there it is done like that as well.
However, if you do not want to adjust the mapping everytime you change the size of the circle, you could use Generated coordinates. Without any mapping, they will always go from 0 to 1 from the front bottom left to the rear top right of the object's bounding box.
Plugging it in at first looks incorrect since it does not have the gradient centered on the circle. That is because the gradient goes from 0 to 1 and the generated coordinates start with 0 at the bottom left as mentioned before (I've scaled the Z component to 0 so we can ignore it in the following explanations on the flat circle):

So how to get the gradient into the center? As you can see, the center is at (0.5, 0.5) and we want this to be 0. Simple solution: set the X and Y location to -0.5 in the Mapping node to subtract 0.5 from the coordinates:

Now this still looks wrong. The gradient does not reach black at the border. The values above show why: the gradient goes from white to black in the 0 to 1 range, but at the border it is only 0.5, because the coordinates are just shifted. To make them become 1 at the border, they have to be scaled by a factor of 2:

But unfortunately now the gradient does not start in the center anymore. Why is that? Because by multiplying the coordinates with 2, the relative location of the circle center has changed. Starting at the bottom left, the circle center is not at 0.5 in X and Y, but at 1. So the location has to changed to -1 on X and Y. Or multiplied by 2 as well. It is basically like this the default generated coordinates go from 0 to 1. to center them on the geometry you have to subtract 0.5 on all axes. And whatever scale factor you apply to the coordinates, this has to be applied to the location as well if you want to keep it centered.

This all seemed more complicated than it is, I just wanted to explain each step to show what is going on there. But the good thing is, once you have set the Scale and Location to match your circle, it will always match no matter if you scale it larger or smaller and even when you scale it in Object Mode and forget to apply the scale it will still match the circle.

